# How to POST to non def post(self) functions in Flask-Classy?

Tags: python, flask

Merry Christmas.

I am not sure if this is possible.  If I have a view-index and I have 2 forms on the view's template, how can I have them direct to different function?

My view code  (as a simple example) is as follows:

```
def deletex(input):
   … 

class AdminView(FlaskView):

    @route('/')
    def index(self):
    return render_template(‘admin-home.html’)

    def delete_x(self, methods=['POST']):
        x = request.form['gid']
        deletex(x)

        flash(“All’s good")
        return redirect(url_for(index))
```

Quite a simple example.  The form on admin-home.html includes this…

```
<form action=“{{ url_for(‘AdminView:delete_x’) }}” method=“post”>
...
```

When I do that it returns a 405 Error.  I can submit forms via GET to delete_x with GET allowed as a method but I can’t find a way to post to a flask-classy view that is not the `def post(self): …`

How can I do this?  Is it possible?  I’d rather not have 2 forms worth of logic in one view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error was because I was putting the `methods=['POST']` in the wrong spot.  I had experimented with it in the function declaration rather than the route decorator.

My class defn is:

```
@route('deletex', methods=['POST'])
def deletex(self):
    pass
```

And then my HTML form is:

```
<form action="{{ url_for("AdminView:deletex") }}" method="post">
```